# DynamoDB table structure - sort by numeric field without any hash key

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, data-modeling

I have a bunch (edit: 2.5 million) of puzzles that I would like to store and query in DynamoDB.

The relevant structure of each puzzle is as follows:

| ID | Difficulty | OtherString | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ab | 1500 | foo1 | ... |
| x0 | 1645 | foo2 | ... |
| c2 | 1645 | foo3 | ... |
| d5 | 1431 | foo4 | ... |
| oz | 1500 | foo5 | ... |

Each `ID` is a unique string. Each `Difficulty` is a numeric value, more or less in the range of 0-3000. There are other fields too but not interesting for this question.

In terms of access patterns, I need to:

1. Update these values from time to time by the `ID`.
2. Get a random puzzle within a given range, e.g. 1500 +/- 50.

I imagine the `ID` is best as the `HASH KEY` but do not believe I can have the `Difficulty` field as the `SORT KEY` as there can be duplicate values. There is nothing else required to partition the data, so no need for any other type of composite key, imo.

Should I just have the `ID` as the `HASH KEY` and do a `scan` operation to get a random puzzle, filtering by the `Difficulty`? Is this possible? is there a better way to model this data? I would imagine having the Difficulty in the `SORT KEY` (somehow) would help speed up searches and use less resources to do so.

Many thanks

Comment: How many puzzles are we talking about here?

Comment: Approx 2.5 million puzzles

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest creating a GSI with the rating as the partition key and the puzzle id as the sort key.

Given there are 2.5 million puzzles and 3,000 difficulty ratings, that's about 1,000 puzzles per rating.

So to pick a random puzzle with a 1500 +/- 50 rating you first (outside the database, in your middleware) randomly pick a rating to use between 1450 and 1550, then you do a query against that GSI PK number to pick a random puzzle within.

How to do that random pick in the query? I'd suggest you (outside the database again) randomly pick a value that fits in the puzzle ID space (`a3` or `r1` or whatever) and do a range query against the SK from the point forward, limit to 1.

Add special handling if no puzzles have the chosen difficulty level (add one to the difficulty and try again) or if no puzzle ids exist in the query (add one to the difficulty and loop around to get the head puzzle of the next difficulty).

The result should be very efficient and affordable.